# How to remove bad disk from LVM2 with the less data loss on other PVs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, lvm

I had a LVM2 volume with two disks. The larger disk became corrupt, so I cant pvmove.
What is the best way to remove it from the group to save the most data from the other disk?
Here is my pvdisplay output:

```
Couldn't find device with uuid WWeM0m-MLX2-o0da-tf7q-fJJu-eiGl-e7UmM3.
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               unknown device
  VG Name               media
  PV Size               1,82 TiB / not usable 1,05 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              476932
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          476932
  PV UUID               WWeM0m-MLX2-o0da-tf7q-fJJu-eiGl-e7UmM3

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name               media
  PV Size               931,51 GiB / not usable 3,19 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              238466
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          238466
  PV UUID               oUhOcR-uYjc-rNTv-LNBm-Z9VY-TJJ5-SYezce
```

So I want to remove the unknown device (not present in the system).
Is it possible to do this without a new disk ? The filesystem is ext4.

Comment: if I would do a `vgreduce --removemissing --force media` what would happen ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
# pvdisplay
Couldn't find device with uuid EvbqlT-AUsZ-MfKi-ZSOz-Lh6L-Y3xC-KiLcYx.
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name               vg_srvlinux
  PV Size               931.51 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              238466
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          238466
  PV UUID               xhwmxE-27ue-dHYC-xAk8-Xh37-ov3t-frl20d

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               unknown device
  VG Name               vg_srvlinux
  PV Size               465.76 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              119234
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          119234
  PV UUID               EvbqlT-AUsZ-MfKi-ZSOz-Lh6L-Y3xC-KiLcYx



# vgreduce --removemissing --force vg_srvlinux


  Couldn't find device with uuid EvbqlT-AUsZ-MfKi-ZSOz-Lh6L-Y3xC-KiLcYx.
  Removing partial LV LogVol00.
  Logical volume "LogVol00" successfully removed
  Wrote out consistent volume group vg_srvlinux

# pvdisplay

 --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name               vg_srvlinux
  PV Size               931.51 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              238466
  Free PE               238466
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               xhwmxE-27ue-dHYC-xAk8-Xh37-ov3t-frl20d
```

now all it work fine!

Comment: Yeah... hope you didn't need LogVol00... it's gone now.

Comment: Better then losing everything...

Comment: oh.. so this is the way to recover from one missing mirror leg `vgreduce --removemissing --force $vgname` ?

Comment: If the disk is bad then the data from the logical volume LogVol00 is already gone. Removing it from the group hasn't removed any more data. Besides, that's what backups are for.

Comment: This has proven useful to me on multiple occasions now in managing ganeti with drbd.

Answer (score 1):

From the `vgreduce` man page:

```
   --removemissing
          Removes all missing physical volumes from the volume group, if there are no  logical  volumes
          allocated  on  those.  This resumes normal operation of the volume group (new logical volumes
          may again be created, changed and so on).

          If this is not possible (there are logical volumes referencing the missing physical  volumes)
          and  you  cannot or do not want to remove them manually, you can run this option with --force
          to have vgreduce remove any partial LVs.

          Any logical volumes and dependent snapshots that were partly on the missing disks get removed
          completely. This includes those parts that lie on disks that are still present.

          If  your  logical  volumes  spanned several disks including the ones that are lost, you might
          want to try to salvage data first by  activating  your  logical  volumes  with  --partial  as
          described in lvm (8).
```

Comment: so basically, if my root `/` has a mirror leg, and that mirror fails, I think the boot will fail, then, with a live distro iso, I can run that command to access again my system? so, also, I think the most safe is to have `/boot` outside of lvm, on a simple 2GB ext4 partition, with the live distro iso?

Comment: @AquariusPower, boot should not fail if one leg of the mirror is missing.  Personally I prefer to use `mdadm` to handle the raid and lvm on top just to divide the array up into logical volumes.  Booting directly from the raid array instead of having a stand alone /boot means the system can still boot up just fine if the primary boot disk dies.

Comment: mmm... I have, on each PV, a small partition for boot, but each partition is independent; so if I put these `/boot` in sync with raid, I can probably fast boot if any of these fail; I like this thanks :), I also guess you prefer mdadm as (maybe?) lvm mirror sync can be slow and not sync enough data in time to ensure safe seamless boot in case one PV fails (like on a blackout).

Comment: @AquariusPower, actually I prefer `mdadm` for the raid both because I prefer raid10 over raid1, and because it can reshape the array ( lvm can't convert a 2 disk mirror into a 3 disk raid5 for instance ).